# TensorFlow Resize image tensor to dynamic shape

Tags: python, image, shapes, tensorflow

I am trying to read some image input for an image classification problem with TensorFlow.

Of course, I am doing this with `tf.image.decode_jpeg(...)`. My images have variable size and hence I am not able to specify a fixed shape for the image tensor.

But I need to scale the images depending on their actual size. Specifically, I want to scale the shorter side to a fixed value and the longer side in a way that the aspect ratio is preserved.

I can get the actual shape of a certain image by `shape = tf.shape(image)`. I am also able to do the computation for the new longer edge like

```
shape = tf.shape(image)
height = shape[0]
width = shape[1]
new_shorter_edge = 400
if height <= width:
    new_height = new_shorter_edge
    new_width = ((width / height) * new_shorter_edge)
else:
    new_width = new_shorter_edge
    new_height = ((height / width) * new_shorter_edge)
```

My problem now is that I cannot pass `new_height` and `new_width` to `tf.image.resize_images(...)` because one of them is a tensor and `resize_images` expects integers as height and width inputs.

Is there a way to "pull out" the integer of the tensor or is there any other way to do my task with TensorFlow?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**

Since I also had [some other issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1029) with `tf.image.resize_images`, here's the code that worked for me:

```
shape = tf.shape(image)
height = shape[0]
width = shape[1]
new_shorter_edge = tf.constant(400, dtype=tf.int32)

height_smaller_than_width = tf.less_equal(height, width)
new_height_and_width = tf.cond(
    height_smaller_than_width,
    lambda: (new_shorter_edge, _compute_longer_edge(height, width, new_shorter_edge)),
    lambda: (_compute_longer_edge(width, height, new_shorter_edge), new_shorter_edge)
)

image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(image, tf.pack(new_height_and_width))
image = tf.squeeze(image, [0])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this is to use the (currently experimental, but available in the next release) [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#cond)* operator. This operator is able to test a value computed at runtime, and execute one of two branches based on that value.

```
shape = tf.shape(image)
height = shape[0]
width = shape[1]
new_shorter_edge = 400
height_smaller_than_width = tf.less_equal(height, width)

new_shorter_edge = tf.constant(400)
new_height, new_width = tf.cond(
    height_smaller_than_width,
    lambda: new_shorter_edge, (width / height) * new_shorter_edge,
    lambda: new_shorter_edge, (height / width) * new_shorter_edge)
```

Now you have `Tensor` values for `new_height` and `new_width` that will take the appropriate value at runtime.

---

*  To access the operator in the current released version, you'll need to import the following:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
```

...and then use `control_flow_ops.cond()` instead of `tf.cond()`.

Comment: That's very nice, cool feature. But my problem still exists. 
`tf.image.resize_images(...)` takes an `int32` as the second and third argument. That's where the values of `new_height` and `new_width` should go.

In my understanding of TensorFlow, a call to `eval()` would not work because this is only evaluated at runtime. Is there any command telling TensorFlow to "pull out the first (and only) integer of the Tensor" at graph building time?

Comment: Calling `tf.image.resize_images(image, new_height, new_width)` always throws `TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.`

Comment: Ah, this seems like a bug to me. I filed [an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1001) and will try to get a fix out soon.

Comment: And I see you already fixed it. Thank you very much, that*s really helping me :)